# AZ Login from CLI issue - SELF SIGNED CERTIFICATE

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, portal

Trying to logon to my Azure portal account through the AZ CLI.

At the az login command I get redirected to a browser to sign into Azure, sign in is successful, CLI says "You have logged in, now let us find all the subscriptions to which you have access..."  Then I get this error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1125)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujMwR.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example before posting questions. Moreover, refrain from posting pictures of error logs, rather paste the logs in question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working behind a corporate proxy, it's most likely that your company's root CA is not added to the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE in python request library that Azure CLI  depends on.

To add the CA,

- Open Chrome, go to portal.azure.com
- Click Connection is secure
- Certificate -> Check if the root CA is public or corporate, if it's a public CA (something like Baltimore...), try go to a different url
- Select certification path and export the top corporate CA to file
- Append the CA to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem`
- [image]

More detailed instruction can be found from this [post](https://jiasli.github.io/azure-notes/cli/cli-proxy.html).

For other OS other than Windows, refer to this [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively#work-behind-a-proxy).

Comment: How do you do this step: "Select certification path and export the top corporate CA to file"?

Comment: @curtispy The link to the post containing more detailed instructions is broken. Any chance you have an alternate link?

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing the issue with the command which you have used, I got redirected to the browser and got back and logged in successfully.

[image]

Referring to the error message which you got looks like you don’t have a fully signed certificate.

To use Azure CLI with the aSDK, you must trust the CA root certificate on your remote machine.

Usually, these certificate locations will depend on where we’ve installed our Python packages

With below command we can get it and make a note of it…

```
python -c "import certifi; print(certifi.where())"
```

Refer to Microsoft [documentation](http://Referring%20to%20the%20error%20message%20which%20you%20got%20looks%20like%20you%20don%E2%80%99t%20have%20a%20fully%20signed%20certificate.%20To%20use%20Azure%20CLI%20with%20the%20aSDK,%20you%20must%20trust%20the%20CA%20root%20certificate%20on%20your%20remote%20machine.%20Usually,%20these%20certificate%20locations%20will%20depend%20on%20where%20we%E2%80%99ve%20installed%20our%20Python%20packages:%20With%20below%20command%20we%20can%20get%20it%20and%20make%20a%20note%20of%20it%E2%80%A6%20%20python%20-c%20%22import%20certifi;%20print(certifi.where())%22%20%20Refer%20to%20Microsoft%20documentation%20for%20Setting%20up%20certificates%20for%20Azure%20CLI) for Setting up certificates for Azure CLI

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to trust the untrusted certificates in the chain for the `az` cli.
This is assuming you want to trust the certificate chain. Mine was broken because of a corporate self-signed certificate.

Use the command to list the certificates in the chain.
`openssl s_client -connect domainYouWantToConnect.com:443 -showcerts`

Then copy each cert and paste it at the end of the `cacert.pem` file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem`

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Certificate stuff....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

You don't need to have any of the `# Issuer: ..` or `# Subject` headers.